# How to copy document of collection keeping document id same between two projects from firestore using python script?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to copy firestore database from production app to development app. My script is generating separate document id for collections and each time the script is run the data is repeated copied. I want to keep the document id same as that of production app so that the data copies only once. Also suggest for copying subcollections to destination project.

code:

```
import firebase_admin

from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

read_objects = []
docid = []
export_db = None
import_db = None
count = 0
export_collection_name = "Resources"
import_collection_name = "Resources"


def batch_data(iterable, n=1):
    l = len(iterable)
    for ndx in range(0, l, n):
        yield iterable[ndx:min(ndx + n, l)]


def init_export_db():
    global export_db
    cred = credentials.Certificate("./path to.json")
    source_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, name="source")
    export_db = firestore.client(app=source_app)


def init_import_db():
    global import_db
    cred = credentials.Certificate("./path to.json")
    destination_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, name="destination")
    import_db = firestore.client(app=destination_app)


def read_data_from_firestore():
    global read_objects, export_db, export_collection_name, count
    docs = export_db.collection(export_collection_name).stream()
    read_objects = []

    # for doc in docs:
    #     print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
    #     obj = doc.to_dict()
    #     read_objects.append(obj)
    #     count += 1
    #     docid.append(doc.id)
    # return docid

    collections = export_db.collection(export_collection_name).document('85lffhHV2vL2VYg00zsc').collections()
    for collection in collections:
        for doc in collection.stream():
            print(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
            obj = doc.to_dict()
            read_objects.append(obj)
            count += 1
            docid.append(doc.id)
            if doc.id == 'zlU6i5tTsEd65Eo6VD0w':
                break
        break
    print(docid)


def write_to_firestore():
    global read_objects, import_db, import_collection_name
    print("uploading to " + import_collection_name)
    # print(read_objects)
    for batched_data in batch_data(read_objects, 10):
        batch = import_db.batch()
        for data_item in batched_data:
            print(data_item)
        # for doc in docid:
            doc_ref = import_db.collection(import_collection_name).document('85lffhHV2vL2VYg00zsc').collection('audio').document()
            # print(doc_ref)
            batch.set(doc_ref, data_item)
        batch.commit()
    print("import DB updated")


# import_db.collection('Resources').document('85lffhHV2vL2VYg00zsc').collection('audio').document()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 0
    init_export_db()
    read_data_from_firestore()
    init_import_db()
    write_to_firestore()
    print("Total " + str(count) + " uploaded")
```

Comment: Anyone please suggest something on this.